# get-windowsfeatures is not recognized in powershell

Tags: powershell

been trying to install windows features using first get-windowsfeature but it says "the term is not recognized . I read online where it says that i should run it in powershell *64 but didn't work either . any help please on how to run it ?

Comment: I am using windows10

Answer (score 2):

The command is `Get-WindowsFeature` (without an "s") and is only availble to server operating systems.

There are some online installs available using the following command:

```
Get-WindowsCapability
```

Or you can add Windows Store packages using:

```
Get-AppxPackage
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10/11 use `Get-WindowsOptionalFeatures -Online` instead

The command `Get-WindowsFeatures` is a Windows server command. It's only available in Windows 10 if you have already installed 'Remote Server Administration Tools'

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Run administrator` if you are using Windows OS.